# Getting "incorrect number of arguments to numeric-type constructor" error in a shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, shaderlab

I've been learning Unity shader for couple of days and decided to port [this](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlcGWr) oil shader from Shadertoy.

I get the following error:

> incorrect number of arguments to numeric-type constructor at line 69
>   (on glcore)

Here is the relevant part of the shader code:

```
#define T (_Time/3.+5.)

fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    float4 fragColor = 0;
    float2 fragCoord = i.vertex.xy;

    float4 k = fragColor;
    float2 p = fragCoord;

    float s = 1.;

    #define rot(p,a) float2 sc = sin(float2(a,a + 1.6));  p *= float2x2(sc.y,-sc.x,sc);

    #define A float3(0,1,157)
    #define B {float2 m = frac(p),l = dot(p - m,A.yz) + A.xz,r = lerp(frac(57.*sin(l++)),frac(57.*sin(l)),(m *= m*(3. - m - m)).x); k += lerp(r.x,r.y,m.y) / (s += s); p *= float4(1,1,1,-1);}

    p *= log(T) / R.y;              // scaling (slow zoom out)
    p.x += T;                       // translation
    rot(p, T / 22.); //ERROR HERE

    //......the rest of the code below
}
```

The `rot(p, T / 22.);` line is where the error is at. The funny thing is that when I remove or comment-out this line of code, the shader compiles and **is working** fine. I still want to know why that line can't compile.

What's causing that error and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by [helium](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6858891/hellium), `float3x3` is a matrix.

Below is the original [rot](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlcGWr) function:

```
#define rot(p,a) vec2 sc=sin(vec2(a,a+1.6)); p*=mat2(sc.y,-sc.x,sc);
```

And the ported version:

```
#define rot(p,a) float2 sc = sin(float2(a,a + 1.6));  p *= float2x2(sc.y,-sc.x,sc);
```

Notice how I replaced `mat2` with `float2x2` because that's the [equivalent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166865.aspx) type in  HLSL.

I do believe that the problem is from `float2x2(sc.y,-sc.x,sc);`. What is the appropriate way to do this and still use the `3` parameters as the original code did?

Comment: I am far from an expert in shaders, but a float3x3 is a matrix constructor waiting for the **rows** of the matrix, right ? But you only specify 3 single floating values. I don't know if it is automatically "converted" to a row with the 3 same components.

Comment: @That's right. It's a matrix and that seems to be the problem when it is called. The original code uses `mat2` but [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn166865.aspx) and [Unity forum](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/glsl-mat2-mat3-equivlants.222790/) says that the appropriate translation is `float2x2`. I am lost on how to make this take 3 parameters like the original code. See my edit to understand what I mean.

Comment: Do you still have the error ? According to this [wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations), The float2x2 can either accept 2 arguments as the rows or 4 parameters as the individual elements of the matrix. I guess you can call the constructor with a 4th argument set to 0.

Comment: tried that but still have the-same problem.

Comment: How about : `float2x2(sc.y,-sc.x,sc.x,sc.y);` since sc is a float2 (works in your Shadertoy)

Comment: Nope. That did not work too. I suspect that we have fixed the part in float2x2. I now think that the remaining error is the function call itself. `rot(p, T / 22.)`.  `rot` is a macro function and I am not sure if the parameter passed into it is correct. Although, it works in `Shadertoy`.

Comment: Then, try to remove the macro definition and use only its "body" as it is.

Comment: Thanks.  I made it into a function like you suggested and it worked very well. I just wanted ti know why it wasn't working since I am new to shaders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in value `_Time` is a `float4` so you have to pick one of the components depending on the time scale you want:

> _Time float4 (t/20, t, t*2, t*3), use to animate things inside the shaders.

for example `#define T (_Time.y/3.+5.)`.

Another thing is the `*` operator for `float2x2` represents a component-wise product of 2 matrices. For vector-matrix/matrix-matrix product you should use the `mul` function.

So in the `rot` function you should have `p =mul(p, float2x2(sc.y,-sc.x,sc));`.

For more info on this you can go to: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cg_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations.

Comment: The `*=` wasn't really the main issue since I've done that already after reading many materials online. The problem is `_Time.y` which you mentioned. I forgot to add the `y` at the end so when I call the `rot` function and pass it `T`, it triggers an error. This actually fixed the problem after adding `.y` to it. Thanks.